How to convert WEBP Mbtiles (512 x 512) to lower resolution (256x256)
I am working on world elevation mbtiles which are in WEBP 512 x 512 resolution. I want to convert this to a lower resolution WEBP 256 x 256. How can I lower the resolution?
I tried gdal-translate, but I am doing something wrong.

What OS?  Linux: magick image.webp -resize "WxH" new_image.webp.
